# Hide table header column border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My table header HTML looks like this

```css
.tablebluelight {
  background: #eef2f7;
  color: #002d62;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-color: #eef2f7;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
  <thead>

    <tr class="tablebluelight">
      <th></th>
      <th>Rod Size</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Rod Angle</th>
      <th>Rod Size</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Rod Angle</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>

    </tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

[image]

I want to remove those white border lines between each column. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just remove the padding between two columns..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `border-spacing: 0px;` to Table element. See this.

```css
.table{
border-spacing: 0px;    
}
.tablebluelight {
  background: #eef2f7;
  color: #002d62;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-color: #eef2f7;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
  <thead>

    <tr class="tablebluelight">
      <th></th>
      <th>Rod Size</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Rod Angle</th>
      <th>Rod Size</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Rod Angle</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>

    </tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `border-spacing: 0;` to the CSS for the table.

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
table {
   border: collapse;
}

th {
  border: none;
}

td {
  border: //What ever you want
}
```

Comment: Or do you want the border around the edge and not the lines between the cells?

Answer (score 1):

usually i would use these ways to make that happen~~

1.
set "cellspacing" as a attribute of that table.

```
<table cellspacing="0"></table>
```

2.set css attribute collapse

```
.table{border-collapse:collapse;}
```

---

as a reminder...dont set border to "tr"...it works awfully...coz it would be covered with border of "td"~~~